# Count down from 0 to 5 seconds and repeat

Tags: sql-server

What query can I use to trigger a count down from 0 to 5 seconds whenever executed? When I execute a query the output has to be 0 second to 5 second and once 5 seconds are done again it should go back to 0. When I execute again it should start from 0 to 5 seconds. Is it possible to achieve something like this using sql query?

Comment: Can I just clarify, do you want to output a count after each second, or just simply wait for 5 seconds. You say the "output" has to be 0 to 5 seconds

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually hoping to achieve here. Certainly, you don't want to just show a countdown on the screen or waste CPU cycles. What are you going to do with this countdown? Other tools are probably more appropriate than a database for them.

Comment: "Count down from 0 to 5"?  Do you mean 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0?

Answer (score 7):

[WaitFor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) should help you accomplish this.

In your case we can simply pass a DELAY time as below

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
```

This will simply wait for 5 seconds, then return to the caller.

Answer (score 6):

Have you looked into the waitfor delay command? See below example

```
while 1=1
begin
    --do something
    waitfor delay '00:00:05'
end
```